# Replacing String Between two special charters in shell script

Tags: shell, replace

I am trying to replace a string in my shell script from localhost:7101/RPAS to sound.mojo.com:5555/rpas in my HTML file.

```
${myDeployment} =<\/td><\td width="0">http://localhost:7101/RPAS<\/td>
```

My output should be:

```
${myDeployment} =<\/td><\td width="0">http://sound.mojo.com:5555/rpas<\/td>
```

1. The strings that are fixed are ${myDeployment} and </td> and localhost:7101 is not a fixed string.
2. http://occurs multiple times in document and the above mentioned string occurs at the last , but not at the end of the document.
3. Is there a way to extend this command to only change the string of the last occurring pattern in the file.

`sed -e 's#>http://[^/]*/#>http://sound.mojo.com:5555\/rpas/#' tst.html`

Please let me know if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed 's#>http://[^/]*/#>http://sound.mojo.com:5555#' file

${myDeployment} =<\/td><\td width="0">http://sound.mojo.com:5555RPAS<\/td>
```

Comment: localhost:7101 is not fixed, even it will change. Only thing that will be fixed is ${myDeployment} and </td>

Comment: It is not working yet. Can you please share the earlier answer as well.

Comment: And the backslash i added coz the editor was taking em as actual tags.They actually are not there in the string.

Comment: can this command be extended to find the last occurrence of the pattern?

Comment: By `last occurrence` you mean in last line or just anywhere `last occurrence`? I also suggest opening a nee question for that requirement since that seems like more complicated regex

Comment: Last occurrence anywhere in the file.

Comment: Hmm that is more complicated problem. Please create a new question with a sample data and you will get quick help here.

Comment: Apparently i cant add more than 2 questions.Could you help me out

Comment: Problem is that sed searches line by line only and doesn't support lookaheads regex, Edit your question and provide a sample data and expected output then I will do some research on my end to answer it.